Updating items of Boolean array in For Each loop
How to update each item of a Boolean array in a For... Each loop?
This code updates item variable in every loop but it doesn't update the array items themselves.
Dim BoolArr(1 to 4) as Boolean
Dim item as Variant
For Each item in BoolArr
    item = True
Next

Dim t as Long
Dim str as String
For t = Lbound(BoolArr) to Ubound(BoolArr)
 str = str & CStr(BoolArr(t))
Next t
Debug.Print str

Shows "FalseFalseFalseFalse".
On the other hand, this For .. To .. loop DOES update array items:
Dim BoolArr(1 to 4) as Boolean
Dim n as Long
For n = Lbound(BoolArr) to Ubound(BoolArr)
    BoolArr(n) = True
Next

Dim t as Long
Dim str as String
For t = Lbound(BoolArr) to Ubound(BoolArr)
 str = str & CStr(BoolArr(t))
Next t
Debug.Print str

Shows "TrueTrueTrueTrue".
How to correct the For Each loop so that it updates array items?

It is a duplication of VBA - Update values in an array with For Each statement

item is a throwaway variable that contains a copy of (eg) BoolArr[t].  Setting item to something is not the same as setting BoolArr[t] to something.

@James Yes, the difference is observed. Is item linked to array items anyway, so updating item updates the array itself?
In contrast, one can update values of cells within a range with For Each loop:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-for-eachnext-statements

updating item updates the array no you can’t - the variable item is completely separate to the array.  If you want to replace an array element use a regular for loop with an index.

Use For loop when iterating an array. Use For Each loop when iterating an object (like a collection, or a range).

@James Yes, item is a separated variable, indeed. This is the answer to the question, I think. That was pointed out also in answers to the duplicated question, that I have found later.

@PéterForgó, Yes, For..To loops can update the array. That was mentioned also in the question itself.

Note that "item as a copy" depends on the type of the array. Since booleans are value types, the variable is always a copy. For reference items, you have a copy of the reference... which may still refer to the same object as the reference in the array.
